# Pass data to variable in swift

Tags: swift

I want to assign button tag to variable. Then I trying send this data to SecondViewController and assign it to var.

```
@IBAction func goToProducts(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: TextStrings.ProfileAluVC.goToProducts, sender: self)
    categoryNumber = sender.tag }
```

Pass data to ProductsViewController

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToProducts" {
        let destinationController = segue.destination as! ProductsViewController
        destinationController.categoryNumb = categoryNumber
    }
}
```

At ProductsViewController I create var but there isn't this data. I print this variable and I get this:

> categoryNumber: 373
>
> categoryNumb: Optional(24)

Can you tell me haw can I do this?

Comment: for starters, if you are using a String Constant as your segue id (which isn't a bad idea, although using an enum is probably more common) then you should use it in `prepare(for:)` too.  If you've got a slight difference between the literal & the constant the value won't be injected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign it first before `performSegue`

```
categoryNumber = sender.tag  
performSegue(withIdentifier: TextStrings.ProfileAluVC.goToProducts, sender: self)
```

---

OR use `sender`

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: TextStrings.ProfileAluVC.goToProducts, sender: sender.tag)
```

Pass data to ProductsViewController

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToProducts" {
        let destinationController = segue.destination as! ProductsViewController
        destinationController.categoryNumb = sender as! Int
    }
}
```